# Android app is not allowing to upgrade to newer version because of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads older version

Tags: android

When we are trying to upgarde the app to newer version on google play store we are getting the following error:

The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) has reported version 11.2.0 as outdated. You must upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+) before you can publish a new release to production.

Learn more about the SDKs that you're using and make informed SDK choices with Google Play SDK Index.

When we change the version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads to 23.2.0 the app does not build successfully and gives errors of duplicate class

In our app we are not using the ad services and wants to remove them but even if we remove these services it is still not allowing us to upgrade the app on google play store - our gradle has following dependencies

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript, PHP, HTML or Google Cloud Platform? When posting a question, only add tags that are actually relevant to the issue.

Comment: A lot has changed since version 11.2.0. It is not surprising that updating the dependency breaks your app. Including the error in your post may help to determine the issue. But in your case, what you probably need is an android developer who can remove or update the whole admob implementation and not just the dependencies.

Comment: Seems the project hasn't been updated in a while. When new dependency versions are published sometimes the code also need to be updated. The more behind the code base is with latest version, the more likely code updates will be required. Also updating a dependency can also require to update another one and it can cascade pretty quickly. Seems, as mentioned above, you'll need to hire a skilled Android engineer to update your project.